# Intersection of the images is trivial, then kernels span the full space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\mathbf{M}_i$ is a set of distinct (no matrix is a multiple or linear combinations of each other) $n$ by $n$ matrices for $i=1,...,n$ and each $\mathbf{M}_i$ is of rank $n-1$. Is it ture that $\bigcap_{i}^n \mathbf{M}_i$ is trivial if and only if the $\ker \mathbf{M}_1+...+\ker\mathbf{M}_n$ is the full vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define linearly independent rank one matrices $M_1,M_2\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ by $M_1=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$ and $M_2=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 3 & 3 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$. Note that we have $$\ker (M_1) = \ker (M_2) =\text{span}\Big\{\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\ -1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)\Big\}$$ $$\text{Col}(M_1) =\text{span}\Big\{\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{smallmatrix}\big)\Big\}$$ $$\text{Col}(M_2) =\text{span}\Big\{\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1\\ 3 \end{smallmatrix}\big)\Big\}$$ Hence $\text{Col}(M_1)\cap \text{Col}(M_2)$ is trivial and $\ker(M_1) + \ker (M_2)\neq \mathbb{R}^2$. So your statement is false.

Comment: How about $\bigcap_{i}^n \mathbf{M}_i$ is trivial if and only if the $\ker \mathbf{M}_1^{T}+...+\ker\mathbf{M}_n^{T}$ is the full vector space?

Comment: This is true, and it's based off the fact that $$\bigg[\ker(M_1^T)+\dots +\ker(M_n^T)\bigg]^{\perp}=\text{Col}(M_1)\cap \ldots\cap \text{Col}(M_n)$$ If you want to see a formal proof of this, let me know. I'll provide you with one

Comment: Thanks, this can be proved by induction right?

Comment: You should notice that, for any matrix $A$, we have $\Big[\text{Col}(A)\Big]^{\perp}=N(A^T)$. Also, if $U_1,\ldots ,U_k$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $$\bigg(U_1 + \ldots + U_k\bigg)^{\perp}=U_1^{\perp}\cap \ldots \cap U_k^{\perp}$$ The latter can be proved directly by mutual inclusion. Combine these two ideas to get the relationship you seek.